# Custom Italic Fonts in Flash

Tags: flash, embedded-fonts

Wonder if anyone has run into a situation in which Flash fails to recognize an embedded font with a title like "Gotham rounded" and a style of "italics?" I can't seem to embed the style because of the double name of the font. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've found similar issues when was trying to embed custom typeface (e.g. "condensed extrabold") from container file format (.ttc, .dfont) into pure AS3 project. Although I haven't tested embedding from container file formats in Flash IDE, I'd recommend you to check how the font you are embedding is stored in your system. If the font is wrapped into container, then try to extract required font-face as a separate .ttf/.otf file (using http://onlinefontconverter.com or other converter), add it to your system, restart Flash IDE, embed font from separated file (font-style property-selector will be inactive), check if required typeface was embedded successfully.